# Find value from mysql column

Tags: mysql, select

I Have following table structure

Table 1:

```
| id | allowed_user_type |
| 1  | 8,9,10  |
```

Table 2:

```
| id | user_type |
| 1  | 9         |
```

so, wanted to check if user_type from Table 2 is exists in allowed_user_type in Table 1: then returns me true otherwise false.

I've used `IN` and `FIND_IN_SET` MySQL statement but no help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your query which you have tried.

Comment: Can you change the table structure?

Comment: @mcalex I know the table structure is not right... but I change it. I have many things to change likewise...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET` works for me.

```
select t1.id, find_in_set(user_type, allowed_user_type) > 0 found
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 using (id);
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93033/1)

But I agree with the other posters that this is poor design. If you have to do it for a large number of rows it will be very slow, because it can't use indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly do some regexp magic to pull the field out of the `allowed_user_type` data.  But it is not worth it.  You **need** to change your table structure.

I'm thinking there's actually a bit more data in the structure of your tables, but in any case, you will make life so much easier for yourself if you rework Table1 to have the following structure:

```
| id | allowed_user_type |
| 1  | 8                 |
| 2  | 9                 |
| 3  | 10                |
```

Then your query is simply

where Table1.allowed_user_type = Table2.user_type

Comment: -1 for your WHERE condition. That will also pass "10", "11" etc. when searching for "1". I agree with rest of the answer.

Comment: she needs a split function and mysql dosent has one

Comment: @mcalex after edit this will not pass first and last value from list in record, because there is no "," before first row and after last :)

Comment: @Arun Killu Mysql dont have split, because there is no need for split in correctly designed relational database.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no correct answer for your question, because question is based on something wrong.**

Your table structure is wrong. It's not "relational", and in addition you have numbers in text fields.

This is very bad design.

What if you want to remove one allowed_user_type? You will need complicated code...

I recommend you to stop working on this, learn some about relational databases and then come back to your project.

Correct design should look like this:

```
Table 1:
| id | allowed_user_type |
| 1  | 8                 |
| 1  | 9                 |
| 1  | 20                |

Table 2:
| id | user_type |
| 1  | 9         |
```

And query like this:

```
SELECT [Table 2].id 
FROM [Table 2], [Table 1]
WHERE [Table 2].user_type in ([Table 1].allowed_user_type);
```

That query will return 0 rows when user is not allowed, or 1 row when user is "allowed". You can also use "count()" function like this:

```
SELECT count([Table 2].id)
FROM [Table 2], [Table 1]
WHERE [Table 2].user_type in ([Table 1].allowed_user_type);
```

That will return 1 row with 1 field containing number of matching rows. 0 will mean "not allowed", "1" will mean "allowed".

Square braces are necessary when you have spaces in table or field names. If you dont have spaces - you dont have to use them.